# Commodities forward curve

Tags: commodities, forward-curve

I'm dealing with the calibration of the forward curve for energy products.
I found an approach proposed by [Benth et al.](https://jod.pm-research.com/content/15/1/52), in which the forward curve is parameterized as $f(t) = s(t) + \epsilon(t)$
where $s$ is the seasonality and $\epsilon$ is a smooth curve used to quantify the deviation from the seasonality. In the paper, $s$ has been chosen according to [Lucia and Schwartz](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013846631785).

My questions are:

1. Which alternatives to Benth et al. are used?
2. Do exist other models other than Lucia and Schwartz for the deterministic function $s$ useful in this setting?

Comment: Is Gabillon model a two factor or one factor model?

Comment: Gabillon: "In this paper, we present a two-variable model of the term structures of futures prices and volatilities assuming that the spot and long-term prices of oil are stochastic, and are the main determinants of the convenience yield function." So yes it is 2 factor even though he does not use the term "factor".

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, an alternative approach is the **Gabillion** two-factor model (which was originally proposed for oil futures).  At a high-level, Gabillon models the spot price as a single-factor Gaussian process that means reverts to a lognormal long-term rate.  See [here](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:a34cee7d-1e96-4507-a24f-0ee42f305acc/download_file?file_format=pdf&safe_filename=The%2Bterm%2Bstructures%2Bof%2Boil%2Bfutures%2Bprices.pdf&type_of_work=Working%20paper) for additional details.